# String in alphabetical order Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string

I am new to Ruby. I have written a solution in Java

```
public boolean checkOrder(String input) {
        boolean x = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length() - 1; i++) {
            if (input.charAt(i) < input.charAt(i + 1) || input.charAt(i) == input.charAt(i + 1)) {
                x = true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return x;

    }
```

I want to do the same in ruby how can I convert the same into ruby. Thanks.

Comment: What does the method do?

Comment: check if a string is in alphabetical order or not.

Comment: Explain, in plain words, what is the method supposed to do? Also, what did you tried?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
def checkOrder(input)
  input.chars.sort == input.chars.to_a
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. What I'm trying to do is to map each line of Java code to Ruby so that I could understand.

Comment: @wali Why do that when it takes one line of Ruby?

Comment: I know java  and trying to learn Ruby from web resources whenever I try to translate it to ruby I get stuck.

Comment: @wali Translating line for line from on language to another is a bad idea. Ruby is vastly different from Java and so, by this simple example here you can see there are no direct mappings there. You're best to drop Java and apply language basics (understand memory, conditionals, loop structures) to Ruby instead of trying to write Ruby like it were Java.

Answer (score 2):

Variation of Sam's answer, in case you ever want this as a String method:

```
class String
  def sorted?
    self.chars.sort == self.chars.to_a
  end
end

'abc'.sorted?
'acb'.sorted?
```

Comment: `self` is the implicit receiver anyway. No need to mention it.

Comment: +1. Adding self is a (bad?) habit I picked up. Due to things like `self[:foo]`, where you can't do without it... :-)

Answer (score 1):

As requested:

```
def checkOrder(input)
  x = false
  (input.length-1).times do |i|
    if input[i] < input[i+1] or input[i] == input[i+1]
      x = true
    else
      return false
    end
  end
  x
end
```

Comment: Alternately, you can say "for i in 0..input.length-1" instead of "input.length.times do |i|"

Comment: There is no need for the last line to be an explicit return, but it shouldn't be returned from within the `times` block either.

Comment: Sam, I think you want `(input.length - 1).times` and your second `return x` needs to move down a line.